# manipulating rows within a group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change value for rows of dataframe after grouping them. 
Specifically I have a dataframe like this:

```
       A   B   C   D
index 
 x     2  1.4  2.3  0
 x     4  2.4  0.5  0
 y     5  3.3  0.3  0
 y     6  1.1  6.3  0
 y     1  3.6  0.2  0
 x     4  0.4  0.9  0
 z     2  0.8  1.1  0
```

I want to groupby index and assign a value to the first n row of each group a and rest another label. So first two rows with x as index will have D=0 , rest D=1

```
    A   B   C   D  
index 
 x     2  1.4  2.3  0
 x     4  2.4  0.5  0
 y     5  3.3  0.3  0
 y     6  1.1  6.3  0
 y     1  3.6  0.2  1
 x     4  0.4  0.9  1
 z     2  0.8  1.1  0
```

Currently I have something like this:

```
 n = 2  
 groups=df.groupby(df.index)
 for key,grp in groups:
     df.loc[key]['D'][0:n-1]=0
     df.loc[key]['D'][n-1:]=1
```

This works on some dataframes and doesn't on others.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an index groupby and then compare the results of `cumcount` to `n`:

```
>>> df["ilab"] = (df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() >= n).astype(int)
>>> df
       A    B    C  D  ilab
index                      
x      2  1.4  2.3  0     0
x      4  2.4  0.5  0     0
y      5  3.3  0.3  0     0
y      6  1.1  6.3  0     0
y      1  3.6  0.2  0     1
x      4  0.4  0.9  0     1
z      2  0.8  1.1  0     0
```

which works because `cumcount` returns a per-group increasing value:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
index
x    0
x    1
y    0
y    1
y    2
x    2
z    0
dtype: int64
```